# What is the Clojure-way of "do additional stuff when ..."

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, conditional-statements

I have a function "`my-func`", that processes the map `x` it gets as a parameter and returns a map. The processing is quite long so here I transferred it to the function `block-with-several-function-calls-on-x`
If the incoming map contains `:special-key`, an additional key-value-pair should be added to the outgoing map.

```
(defn my-func [x]
  (if (contains? x :special-key)
    (assoc (block-with-several-function-calls-on-x x)
           :extra-key true)
    (block-with-several-function-calls-on-x x)))
```

I'd really like to keep the code of `block-with-several-function-calls-on-x` within `my-func`. I other programming languages, I'd simply save the output of that part within a variable and (if necessary) add the additional part afterwards and than return the value. I was told that using `let` is not "Clojuresque".

So is transferring the code to a function (as I did above) the only way? or is the a `do-additonal-stuff-to-output-of-second-block`-function:

```
(defn my-func [x]
  (do-additional-stuff-to-output-of-second-block
    (when (contains? x :special-key)
      (assoc :extra-key true))
    (block-with-several-function-calls-on-x x)))
```

Comment: "using let is not Clojuresque" -- this is absurd and hilariously wrong and the person who said it doesn't know much about Clojure

Comment: perhaps there was some miscommunication? for example, let does not create "variables". Regardless, the standard way to do this is to use let.

Answer (score 3):

`cond->` and `cond->>` are conditional versions of `->` and `->>` and might fit your need:

```
(defn my-func
  [x]
  (cond-> (block-with-several-function-calls-on-x x)
    (contains? x :special-key) (assoc :extra-key true)
    (contains? x :other-key)   (dissoc :we-dont-need-this)))
```

Although, with only one condition this might not be the epitome of readability.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the advice you've had, I'd use `let`:

```
(defn my-func [x]
  (let [ans (block-with-several-function-calls-on-x x)]
    (if (contains? x :special-key)
      (assoc ans :extra-key true)
      ans)))
```

Notes:

- The only value you mention is boolean. If *all* your values are
  boolean, use a set, not a map.
- If not, I doubt that you have false (`false` or `nil`) values. In
  their absence, you can replace `(contains? x :special-key)` with 
  `(x :special-key)` or `(:special-key x)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following option might be more idiomatic and concise than your current one. It avoids repeating the call to the `block-with-several-function-calls-on-x` function and uses `when` to convey the meaning of the lack of an alternative in the conditional.

```
(defn block-with-several-function-calls-on-x [x]
  x)

(defn my-func [x] 
  (into (block-with-several-function-calls-on-x x)
        (when (contains? x :special-key)
          {:extra-key true})))

(my-func {:bla 1 :special-key 2})
;= {:bla 1, :special-key 2, :extra-key true}
(my-func {:bla 1})
;= {:bla 1}
```